# Setting/Destroying Cookies across protocols

Tags: php, .net, cookies

I have two sites on the same domain running different platforms:

```
Site 1: http://www.domain.ie = PHP/CI Platform
Site 2: https://secure.domain.ie = .NET Proprietary system
```

The Cookies set on Site 1 are set as follows:

```
session.cookie_httponly Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0
session.cookie_path     /
session.cookie_secure   Off
```

In addition, the cookie domain is set to .domain.ie

When a user logs into Site 1, a number session cookies are set to tokenize and identify the user. When they traverse to the secure (https) site, the .NET site detects the presence of these cookies, and cross-authenticates and the system works fine.

However, we're now getting a situation where we need to synchronise the logging off from the system. If a user logs off from Site 1, the system destroys the session cookies and the user is effectively logged out, when they go to Site 2, if the session doesn't exist - they are prompted to log in.

The problem we're having is that if the user logs out of Site 2, we've been trying to destroy the session cookies which were set on Site 1, but we only appear to have ReadOnly access to the cookie - we're unable to destroy/overwrite the cookie.

I thought the whole point of setting cookie_secure to off and httponly to off was that they could share the resource?

Anyone know of a way that we can make this principle work?

Comment: If the cookie domain is set to .domain.ie you are right. Try debugging (using firebug for example) to see what the exact cookie looks like that is set by PHP and your .NET environment. They probably don't look equal.

Comment: Yep - I've looked and they are identical. I can read them on both sites as fine, but we can't overwrite/destroy it on the https[://]secure.domain.ie domain (however, the same code if we go to http[://]secure.domain.ie works).

Comment: Does not directly makes sense; You are 100% sure that both environments set the 'secure' flag to no?

Comment: Yes, 100%. It appears that the cookie is readonly on the https environment, but not so on the same site if its executed over http.

Comment: Have you tested this with different browsers?